# DynamoDBMapper support for inheritance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using dynamodb and the java class I'm storing has the following structure:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="Animals")
class abstract Animal {

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Id")
  @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
  String id;

}

class Dog extends Animal {
  // ... dog props
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  // ... cat props
}
```

I would like to save instances of Dog/Cat to the db and retrieve them as well. Ready to supply meta information similar to `@JsonTypeInfo` and the likes.

Let me know if this is supported. Or any workarounds for storing polymorphic types from Java in DynamoDb.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

You can use the inheritance concept as you described above. The DynamoDBMapper save() method should be able to save Dog and Cat successfully.

However, when you retrieve the data using DynamoDBMapper load(), you need to provide correct class name.

When you execute the load () method with Animal.class, the API will throw "Failed to instantiate class" exception if Animal class is defined as abstract.

**Example load() method to get Animal data:-**

```
dynamoDBMapper.load(Animal.class,id,
                    new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT));
```

**Exception:-**

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Failed to instantiate class
```

**Workaround 1:-**

You can get the Animal data using **QuerySpec**. The disadvantage of this is that you need to get the value for each key individually as you are not getting the data using DynamoDBMapper class.

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamoDBClient);

        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("Animals");

        ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = null;

        QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec();

        querySpec.withKeyConditionExpression("Id = :val1").withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":val1", animalId));
        items = table.query(querySpec);

        Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Item itemData = iterator.next();

            System.out.println("Json data ====================>" + itemData.toJSONPretty());
            System.out.println("Dogname : " + itemData.getString("dogname"));
            System.out.println("Catname : " + itemData.getString("catname"));

        }
```

**Workaround 2:-**

You can declare the Animal class as normal class (i.e. without abstract). In this approach, you can get the data using DynamoDBMapper. However, you will not see the child class attributes.

If you know that you are going to get CAT or DOG object, you can specify that as class name accordingly during load().

**When you get DOG:-**

```
Dog dog = dynamoDBMapper.load(Dog.class, id,
                    new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT));
```

**When you get CAT:-**

```
Cat cat = dynamoDBMapper.load(Cat.class, id,
                    new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT));
```

Comment: This means, when saving I could save either Dog/Cat and it would be saved to the db (possibly along with additional field 'type' == 'Dog'/'Cat' in the Animal class). While retrieving I should read using QuerySpec, and read as JSON, and depending upon the type, pass the appropriate clazz to jackson and deserialise it. 

Is that correct? But I would have expected the SDK to support this by default just like hibernate as document databases are naturally polymorphic.

Comment: ** (possibly along with additional field 'type' == 'Dog'/'Cat' in the Animal class) - I meant manually adding the type info.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. You can save the data successfully along with the additional field. Also, Dynamodb is a key/value database.

Comment: Was this answer helpful?

Comment: Finally used the low level api ("Item" api) and did the serialization/deserialization outside dynamo using Jackson.

Comment: An alternative to workaround 2 (with the same effect) would be to declare a class "DynamoAnimal extends Animal", and only use this when loading from dynamo. You'd still only get the "Animal" attributes, but you could also keep Animal as an abstract class.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [@DynamoDBDocument](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBDocument) to serialize objects. The documentation has a nice example to demonstrate the usage of this annotation as well.